# Azure MSAL login issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD B2C and trying to login using username and password in my Xamarin app. After signup, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: Returned user identifier does not match the sent user identifier at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.SaveTokenResponseToCache ()

I am using MSAL for login and when we try to log in with Facebook, it works perfectly.

I found another thing, when I try to login with sign up or sign in policy, I can only login with Facebook, but when i try to login only with sign in policy I can only login with username and password not using Facebook.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5201635/27732243-fcf1db82-5dad-11e7-9aa7-0796594554a6.jpg]

Comment: From error message , seems you pass different user identifier to acquire token , please check that firstly .

Answer (score 0):

MSAL has a user cache that requires you to pass in a User in your `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` calls.

In the case of Azure AD B2C, the user entries in the MSAL cache don't map 1-to-1 to B2C users, rather they are projected across the different policies being used.

So if you have an app that leverages 3 policies for 1 user, MSAL's user cache will have 3 entries in the user cache.

From a code perspective, this means that in order to use MSAL you need to:

1. Have a `GetUserByPolicy` helper method that obtains the appropriate user cache entry based on the policy and using that to obtain the user that's passed in to your `AcquireTokenAsync` and `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` calls.
2. Ensure you are always passing an Authority value in your `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` calls.

The error "Returned user identifier does not match the sent user identifier" is generally caused by either of these two not being done correctly.

From the [Azure AD B2C Xamarin Sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/):

`AcquireTokenAsync` call:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(App.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), App.Authority, false);
```

`AcquireTokenSilentAsync` call:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), App.UiParent);
```

`GetUserByPolicy` helper method:

```
private IUser GetUserByPolicy(IEnumerable <IUser> users, string policy)
{
  foreach (var user in users)
  {
    string userIdentifier = Base64UrlDecode(user.Identifier.Split('.')[0]);
    if (userIdentifier.EndsWith(policy.ToLower())) return user;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm late to the party on this, but in case this helps someone else then this is what worked for me when the 'Returned user identifier does not match the sent user identifier' error appeared.

Try adding this before the AquireLoginAsync / AquireLoginSilentAsync, it will clear any old USER objects from the cache.

```
foreach (var user in ActiveDirectoryB2CAuthenticationClient.Users)
{
    ActiveDirectoryB2CAuthenticationClient.Remove(user);
}
```